# Error in loading a data from the txt file to oracle table using sqlldr

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

my .ctl file is :

```
LOAD DATA
  INFILE "C:\Users\nkb1\Desktop\fnames.txt"
  INTO TABLE MDB.TEACHERS
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  (first_name,last_name)
```

i am executing this from the windows command prompt as

```
sqlldr system@mdb/mdb control=C:\Users\nkb1\Desktop\load.ctl
```

and i am getting error like this.

```
 C:\Users\nkb1>sqlldr system@mdb/mdb control=C:\Users\nkb1\Desktop\load.ctl
 SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed May 4 14:44:22 2011

 Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

 SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIEnvCreate [-1]
```

and i have set the `ORACLE_HOME` variable as `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2` where the db stores

Answer (score 2):

Bad news, this is a bug in 10.2.0.1.

Check Metalink document 361325.1 (hope you have access)!

Maybe you'll just have to grant additional privileges but it is possible that you'll need to apply the 10.2.0.3 patch set

Comment: I suspect if @Navin had a Support account they wouldn't still be running the base release of 10g.  Oracle used to host the stable 10.2.0.4 release on OTN, but it looks like they now only make 11gR2 available from that place.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue. Closed the command prompt.Opened one with Administrator Rights - Open CMD as Administrator.

That's it. This solved all the issues I had been facing.

If you have saved the SQLLOADER/SQLPLUS scripts as a batch file, then submit/open the batch file as administrator .

Hope this helps.